# Couchbase 1.8.0 some queries

Tags: couchbase

Few queries regarding couchbase 1.8.0

1. Does putting blank value deletes the key or the key remains as it is
2. Is there any way to get all the keys from a bucket. Is there any ways to flush keys from a bucket from Admin panel.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, blank is a "value", and you cannot send null (at least from Java). So you need to remove it using a delete operation or a TTL.
2. Not in 1.8, in Couchbase 2.x you can create a simple view that emit(meta.id) and query this view.